# Create a new DataFrame using pandas date_range

Tags: python, pandas, date, range

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   date_start          date_end
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 2023-01-01 17:00:00
1  2023-01-02 16:00:00 2023-01-02 17:00:00
2  2023-01-03 16:00:00 2023-01-03 17:00:00
3  2023-01-04 17:00:00 2023-01-04 19:00:00
4  NaN                 NaN
```

and I want to create a new DataFrame which will contain values starting from the `date_start` and ending at the `date_end` of each row.
So for the first row by using the code below:

```
new_df = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=df['date_start'][0], end=df['date_end'][0], freq= '15min'))
```

I get the following:

```
0   2023-01-01 16:00:00
1   2023-01-01 16:15:00
2   2023-01-01 16:30:00
3   2023-01-01 16:45:00
4   2023-01-01 17:00:00
```

How can I get the same result for all the rows of the df combined in a new df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start=start, end=end,
                                                     freq='15min')})
                  for start, end in zip(df['date_start'], df['date_end'])],
                ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
                  date
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00
2  2023-01-01 16:30:00
3  2023-01-01 16:45:00
4  2023-01-01 17:00:00
5  2023-01-02 16:00:00
6  2023-01-02 16:15:00
7  2023-01-02 16:30:00
8  2023-01-02 16:45:00
9  2023-01-02 17:00:00
10 2023-01-03 16:00:00
11 2023-01-03 16:15:00
12 2023-01-03 16:30:00
13 2023-01-03 16:45:00
14 2023-01-03 17:00:00
15 2023-01-04 17:00:00
16 2023-01-04 17:15:00
17 2023-01-04 17:30:00
18 2023-01-04 17:45:00
19 2023-01-04 18:00:00
20 2023-01-04 18:15:00
21 2023-01-04 18:30:00
22 2023-01-04 18:45:00
23 2023-01-04 19:00:00
```

##### handling NAs:

```
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start=start, end=end,
                                                     freq='15min')})
                  for start, end in zip(df['date_start'], df['date_end'])
                  if pd.notna(start) and pd.notna(end)
                ],
                ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: @thanks mozway! In case there are NaNs, I am getting the following error:
`ValueError: Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT`. How do I ignore the NaNs?

Comment: You can first run `df2 = df.dropna(['date_start', 'date_end'])` and use `df2` in the list comprehension. Or add `if pd.notna(start) and pd.notna(end)` as test at the end of the list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer that `date_range` has a `to_series()` method and that you could proceed like this as well:

```
pd.concat(
  [
    pd.date_range(start=row['date_start'], end=row['date_end'], freq= '15min').to_series()
    for _, row in df.iterrows()
  ], ignore_index=True
)
```